# Heuristic Malware Detection Methods

Tags: antivirus, antimalware, detection

I would like to know some basic heuristic detection methods in detail because when I do research there is only a general overview of heuristics and not what methods are used to achieve it. I would appreciate some information that has an example (code, or explanation) of how the method works.

Comment: Have you tried YARA?

Comment: @mootmoot Yes i have but i would class yara as more of a string signature method then heuristic. Do you agree?

Comment: YARA heuristic rules can be extended to use complicate stuff, e.g. regex, or even fuzzy hash. The caveats of YARA : if the function is not there, you need to write a wrapper for it ;-)

Comment: @mootmoot  Thanks i will look into that do you know any articles on it. Also do you know anyother methods?

Comment: Honestly, when you create a computer conditions code, most of them are heuristic.

Comment: @mootmoot ok by any chance do you know any methods i can intergrate into python becuase im trying to make a basic malware detection program?

Comment: https://www.bsk-consulting.de/2015/02/16/write-simple-sound-yara-rules/

Comment: @mootmoot Thanks i will read that! Are you aware of any techniques other than yara?

Comment: There is a few open source AV project, but Yara framework is great for quickstart.

Comment: @mootmoot Want to write it up in an answer?

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/how-do-anti-virus-programs-catch-a-virus-how-they-detect-it/3979#3979 and https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4546/how-to-decide-file-is-malware-or-not/4548#4548